# Add a new records to a cell array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I am using the following function in matlab:

```
getgenpept(AccessionNumber)
```

where the only parameter is a unique identifier. The problem is that I want to have a structure with around 50 different records all based on their unique identifier. Is there a way I can define a structure, and then add in my 50 different records as I go along, or ideally specify a list of identifiers before hand and loop the `getgenpept()` function in one go?

I want to end up with a cell array that stores each record in their own cell.

Hope this is clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A is a cell array containing all the identifiers, then it's as easy as:

```
A = {'AAA59174', 'AAA59175','AAA59176'};
B = cellfun(@getgenpept,A);
```

B(1) is then the record for 'AAA59174', and so on.